# set default microphone from c#

Tags: c#, winapi, audio, naudio

I am trying to set the default microphone device on windows 10 and 11. I can list all the devices okay, including getting the current default device. But I cannot find a way to set the default device.

NAudio does not have an API for doing that, so I am trying to use the waveInXXX API instead. But I cannot find an API that will switch the default microphone.

I even tried the new MS Bing AI chat (ChatGPT), which gave me the following code, including a Win32 declaration. Unfortunately, I don't think the API exists!

```
  // from Bing AI Chat
  // [DllImport("winmm.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
  // static extern int waveInSetDefault(int uDeviceID);
  // waveInSetDefault(i);
```

My question is how to set the default microphone device. NAudio doesn't have an API (that I can find). The waveXXX methods do not have an API that I can find (despite the MS AI saying that such an API exists). Is there any way to set the default device from C# without using a Powershell library? (which I have not yet tested)

```
  // here is my code (that fails on the waveInSetDefault(i) call)

  public static void
    WaveInputDeviceDefaultSet(string match, out WAVEINCAPS defaultDevice) {
    WaveInputDevicesAllGet(out var waveDevices);
    defaultDevice = waveDevices.First();

    // set the default device by its index
    for (var i = 0; i < waveDevices.Count; i++) {
      if (waveDevices[i].szPname.Contains(match)) {
        var code = waveInSetDefault(i);
        defaultDevice = waveDevices[i];
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Select an audio input device with the Speech SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-select-audio-input-devices) and [Access Microphone Audio with C#: How to use NAudio to sample microphone audio in a C# application](https://swharden.com/csdv/audio/naudio/)

Comment: Thank you. I can enumerate the audio devices okay, but I want to set the default microphone device. (My other software speech recognizer can only access the default microphone device, so I want to be able to change the default device.) As far as I can tell, the Speech SDK does not allow you to change the default device.

Comment: [IPolicyConfig](https://github.com/xenolightning/AudioSwitcher/blob/27d4bf54b3be588b798f85100e58a148c5fcc234/AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio/Internal/PolicyConfig.cs#L8) can set the default endpoint.

Comment: Thank you! That looks much more promising - I will check it out. I would never have thought to search for that string (IPolicyConfig), for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [I said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76302848/set-default-microphone-from-c-sharp#comment134554934_76302848) in comments, the well-known undocumented interface [IPolicyConfig](https://github.com/xenolightning/AudioSwitcher/blob/27d4bf54b3be588b798f85100e58a148c5fcc234/AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio/Internal/Interfaces/IPolicyConfig.cs)
is used to cooperate with endpoints. You can try *`IPolicyConfig::SetDefaultEndpoint`*.